Проблема с установкой TDlib
Решил скачать TDlib по инструкции с сайта https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD (система windows, язык программирования python), но при вводе  ./vcpkg.exe install gperf:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows zlib:x64-windows, выводит сообщение -
**Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
gperf:x86-windows -> 3.1#6
openssl:x86-windows -> 3.1.4#1

vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows -> 2023-05-04
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows -> 2022-02-06#1
vcpkg-cmake-get-vars:x64-windows -> 2023-03-02
zlib:x86-windows -> 1.3
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance
Could not locate a complete Visual Studio instance
The following paths were examined for Visual Studio instances:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary/Build\vcvarsall.bat
**
Что с эти сделать и в чём проблема?


К своему вопросу, после ссылки на конструктор Вам надо указать последовательность команд (которые получили в конструкторе) - это будет информативней.

И вывод в консоль надо бы полный, не понятна проблема. (Выглядит так, как будь-то пытаетесь установить неподходящую версию.
